# Codeigniter send the password through email

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am making a registration in which you would only provide your email and name
when the email is sent for verification I want the password to be random generated and that would be emailed to the user how can i do this

here is my controller:

```
public function register() {
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First Name', 'required');
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last Name', 'required');
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'E-mail', 'required|valid_email');
          if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

              $registration_data = array(
                  'user_firstname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
                  'user_lastname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
                  'user_email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                  'user_password' =>md5(rand(0, 50)),
                  'user_status' => '0',
                 'hash' => md5(rand(0, 1000))
              );
              $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
              $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
              $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
              $config['smtp_user'] = 'sampleemail';
              $config['smtp_pass'] = 'samplepass';
              $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
              $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
              $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
              $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes
              $this->email->initialize($config);
       $address = $this->input->post('email');
          $this->user_model->insert_customer($registration_data);
         $this->load->library('email');     //load email library
        $this->email->from('sampleemail', 'Site'); //sender's email
        $subject="Welcome!";    //subject
        $message= /*-----------email body starts-----------*/
          'Thanks for signing up, '.$_POST['fname'].'!

          Your account has been created. 
          Here are your login details.
          -------------------------------------------------
          Email   : ' . $_POST['email'] . '
          Password: ' . $_POST['password'] . '
          -------------------------------------------------

          Please click this link to activate your account:

          ' . base_url() . 'user/verify?' . 
          'email=' . $_POST['email'] . '&hash=' . 'hash';

        /*-----------email body ends-----------*/             
        $this->email->to($address);
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);
        $this->email->send();


      }
```

i think his problem that password doesn't send to user

Comment: what is this not doing that you expect to do? Where is the problem occuring? Are you seeing any error output? Do you have errors turned on? Also, punctuation is your friend.

Comment: the password is not sent in the email

Comment: This is rather bad practice, in terms of security. You should only send them a link, containing a one-time token, to a form where they can set a new password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code is not clear to me.

Your data are saved in this array

```
$registration_data = array(
                  'user_firstname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
                  'user_lastname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
                  'user_email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                  'user_password' =>md5(rand(0, 50)),
                  'user_status' => '0',
                 'hash' => md5(rand(0, 1000))
              );
```

Try to send the password through this array. Like example:

```
$registration_data['user_password'];
```

Because the password has been generated in your code and it did not ended by user.

Answer (score 0):

First you should get password from data base and email it.

you doesn't have any posted password in this line " $_POST['password']" to send to user .

Comment: are there any way that i could post the random string and at the same time that would be the one stored in the database ?